# Using string content into another program in CPP

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to use the string content read from one program into another program. I have put some sample code to reproduce the example. I have a `main` function

```
//main.cpp
#include "read.h"
#include "read_fasta.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
    index();
    read_fasta_file(argc,argv); 

    std::cout << " : " << content << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Length of fasta file: " << content.length() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I read `fasta` file

```
//read_fasta.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "read_fasta.h"

std::string content;

int read_fasta_file(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
     std::string line, name;
     while( std::getline( input, line ).good() ){
           if( line.empty() || line[0] == '>' ){ // Identifier marker
             if( !name.empty() ){ // Print out what we read from the last entry
                 std::cout << name << " : " << content << std::endl;
                    name.clear();
                }
                if( !line.empty() ){
                    name = line.substr(1);
                }
                content.clear();
            } else if( !name.empty() ){
                if( line.find(' ') != std::string::npos ){ // Invalid sequence--no spaces allowed
                    name.clear();
                    content.clear();
                } else {
                    content += line;
                }
            }
        }
        if( !name.empty() ){ // Print out what we read from the last entry
            std::cout << name << " : " << content << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Length of fasta file: " << content.length() << std::endl;
        }   
        return 0;

    }
```

Header file of `read_fasta.cpp`

```
//read_fasta.h
#ifndef read_fasta_h
#define read_fasta_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int read_fasta_file(int argc, char **argv);

extern std::string content;

#endif
```

Till now every thing works fine. Now i try to use the `std::string content` in another `cpp` progam.

```
//read.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "read.h"

void index() 
{

std::cout<<"Do U see any printing :"<<content<<std::endl;

}
```

Header file for `read.cpp`

```
//read.h
#ifndef read_h
#define read_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void index(); 
extern std::string content;

#endif
```

But there seem to be nothing in `std::string content` in `read.cpp` program. I am missing something.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying that when you call index() you see nothing printed? Because that's obvious as content hasn't been set yet.

Comment: @wyas U understood right.  On calling `index()`, nothing is printing, however `std::string content` is global and already have content in it.

Comment: There is a content variable inside read.h. When you call index(), content is still empty so nothing will be printed. This call "std::cout<<"Do U see any printing :"<<content<<std::endl;" will obviously print nothing. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @wyas  If your look at `read_fasta.h`, i have declared `std::string content` as global, so it should be accessible anywhere.

Comment: No, that content is at read_fasta.cpp file scope. It doesn't reach anything outside of it. It's not the same content variable as the one in read.cpp.

Comment: @wyas . Ok, how to make it accessible to `read.cpp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111089/discussion-between-hashim-and-wyas).

Comment: Your question was answered in first comment. `content` is empty when you call `index()`. It is filled later.

Comment: Oh!! bad. I need to call   `read_fasta_file(argc,argv)` and then `index() `.